# Recursively traversing a tree to print values within a range

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I have the following question:

*Given a Binary Search Tree and two numbers - a & b, return all the nodes in the tree that lie in the range [a .. b]. Your method should return an ArrayList with the data of the qualifying nodes inserted in ascending order.*

This is the provided solution code, with my comments expressing my "theory" on why the recursion is written that way:

```
public  ArrayList<Integer> rangeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void printRange(TreeNode root, int a, int b) {
    if(root == null){return ;}

    //check if there's something lower that needs to be added first
    //go down root.left
    if(root.data >= a){
        printRange(root.left, a, b);
    }

    //if within the range, add it to result list 
    if(root.data >= a && root.data <= b){
        rangeList.add(root.data);
    }

    //?????????
    if(root.data <= b){
        printRange(root.right, a, b);
    }
```

I cannot figure out third portion of the code. Why do we traverse the right subtree if root.data <= b?

It seems to me it is unnecessary to do so because we already know root.data <= b.

Anything > b would be ineligible to be put into our answer array. Yet we traverse down the right subtree.

Can anyone clarify?

Edit:

here is an example test case and solution:

```
Example:  
       4                                  
      / \                              
     2   8  
        / \                     
       5  10                  

Range (2,8) ==> [2, 4, 5, 8]

Range includes 2 & 8
```

Comment: "It seems to me it is unnecessary to do so because we already know root.data <= b." From what do you know that?

Comment: I guess it is possible that root.right could also be <= b so it makes sense to traverse it...but I'm struggling to see the intuition behind the approach.

Comment: You need to be more specific. If it's about intuition, then you should ask your teacher at school, not on Stack Overflow. This code does simple in-order traversal. Try to do it step by step on a paper. Take a pause and continue tomorrow. A tip: Sometimes you just need to accept something as it is and continue studying. You don't need to understand everything intuitively immediately. Then as you progress in your studies, you'll notice that previous things get clearer and clearer. Don't forget to repeat topics.

Comment: If you don't explore the right subtree (the recursive call with the ???????? comment), how can you possibly expect a correct algorithm? On your example, you'd skip exploring the subtree rooted at 8 and wind up with `[2,4]`. If you're not sure what the code does, comment it out and run the algorithm.